# Some html refactoring

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, refactoring

So I made a website for selling books (just for practice). It has a books section where I show all the books categorized in rows just like the netflix. If I click to the book's image there comes up a little popup box where you can read some details. The content of the popups of course different and this is my problem (the html structure the same every time, so it is just ctrl+c ctrl+v)(of course it is so bad). I need to build every popup line-by-line and it takes much time and really hard to follow, easy to make typos etc. I don't know is it possible to reduce the number of lines.

This is the structure of a book before click.

```
<div class="book-list-row-element"><img class="images" id="remalmok-image" src="images/remalmok.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

This is the structure of 1 popup box

```
<div class="popup-remalmok">
        <div class="popup-book-content">
            <img class="book-remalmok-close" src="images/close.png" alt="">
            <div class="popup-book-header">
                <img class="popup-book-img" src="images/remalmok.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="popup-book-data">
                <p>Publisher: Magveto kiado</p>
                <p>Number of pages: 241</p>
                <p>Language: Hungarian</p>
                <p>Date of public: 1988</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-book-body">
                <div class="body-content">
                    <p class="body-content-p">Original price: 5000</p>
                    <p class="body-content-p">New price: 4999</p>
                    <p class="body-content-p">In stock!</p>
                    <p class="body-content-p">Transport: 1-3 days</p>
                </div>
                <p class="basket">Add to basket</p>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

So as I said the main problem is that the content of popups are different. For example the main space for books before click (one space in a row) only costs 1 line because they are the same, them just boxes.
Want to make it with less code if it is possible please share with me :)
If I explained poorly please tell the problem and I will try again.
Thank you!

Comment: What is your current clickhandler's code?

Comment: Since you're writing data manually there will be lots of repetition, i suggest putting said data in a database or array of objects which you can then loop through with a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my onpinion I try it with an array

Comment: @Gufi good luck, we'll be here should you face any obstacle.